# I have a problem with JAvaScript Arrays and Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

A newbie here. I started to learn some coding like 1 weeks ago. And I'm having trouble with my code. I just want to print employers name who's score is bigger than 4 .

Here is my code:

```js
const employers = [
  { name: "Adam", score: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", score: 3 },
  { name: "Lucas", score: 3 },
  { name: "Francesca", score: 2 },
  { name: "Mason", score: 4 }
]

function getEmployer(employerList) {
  let List = [employers];
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
    if(List['score'] > 4 ) {
        return List[i].name;
      }
  }
  
}


console.log(getEmployer(employers))
```

Could you give me some details about it ?

Comment: you are indexing List (an array of array) using a string 'score' this results always in undefined and the if condition is always evaluated to false so the function always return undefined. The syntax: [employers] create a new array and put the employers array inside it.

Comment: There's no need for `let List = [employers]`. Just loop through `employerList`.

Comment: What if there are more than one employers with scores bigger than 4? You'll only return the first one. You should put all the matches in an array, and return that at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of your code `let List = [employers];` you are putting your array argument inside an array that you do not need and you are not passing index inside if . You can fix your code in this way however this solution will print just the first match

```js
const employers = [
  { name: "Adam", score: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", score: 3 },
  { name: "Lucas", score: 3 },
  { name: "Francesca", score: 2 },
  { name: "Mason", score: 4 }
]

function getEmployer(employerList) {

  for (let i = 0; i < employerList.length; i++) {
    if(employerList[i]['score'] > 4 ) {
        return employerList[i].name;
      }
  }
  
}


console.log(getEmployer(employers))
```

You can return an employers array to show all matches in this way

```js
const employers = [
  { name: "Adam", score: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", score: 3 },
  { name: "Lucas", score: 3 },
  { name: "Francesca", score: 2 },
  { name: "Mason", score: 4 },
  { name: "Lucas2", score: 8 },
  { name: "Francesca2", score: 2 },
  { name: "Mason2", score: 7 }
]

function getEmployer(employerList) {
  let matchedEmployers = [];
  
  employerList.forEach((employer) => {
    if(4 < employer.score) {
      matchedEmployers.push(employer.name)
    }
  })
  return matchedEmployers;
}


console.log(getEmployer(employers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, similar to what you did. See the comments next to the lines for explainations.

```js
const employers = [
  { name: "Adam", score: 5 },
  { name: "Jane", score: 3 },
  { name: "Lucas", score: 3 },
  { name: "Francesca", score: 2 },
  { name: "Mason", score: 4 }
]

function getEmployer(employerList) {
  let list = []; // Empty array to store the results in.
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < employerList.length; i++) { // Loop over the items in 'employerList', 
    if(employerList[i].score > 4 ) {
        list.push(employerList[i]); // Add the item from employerList to the array with results. 
      }
  }
  return list; // Return the array with results. 
}


console.log(getEmployer(employers))
```

Comment: Than you for your help

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a `for` loop here when you can use `forEach` -  you can loop directly through your array that is passed as an argument to the function.

Also, added an array to hold more than one array element where `score` is greater than `4`.

```js
const employers = [{
    name: "Adam",
    score: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    score: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Lucas",
    score: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Francesca",
    score: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Mason",
    score: 4
  }
]

function getEmployer(employerList) {
  // Let's have a holder for all that are greater than 4.
  let highScore = [];
  
  // Make sure you are actually passing an array.
  if (Array.isArray(employerList)) {
    // Loop through what is passed.
    employerList.forEach((elem) => {
      // If the array element score is greater than 4, let's push it into our highScore array.
      if (elem.score > 4) {
        highScore.push(elem);
      }
    });
  }
  
  // Return it!
  return highScore;
}

console.log(getEmployer(employers));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think I should learn more about it because I felt Im really confused about the loop and array concepts.